# Not Able to print the matrix elements through functions

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm not able to print the elements of a matrix through function.

Below is the code I have written. Please help me by replying by a solution.

```
main() {
    int m[10][10], r, c, m_sum;
    add_elements(m, r, c);
    print_elements(m, r, c, m_sum);
}
add_elements(int m[10][10], int r, int c, int m_sum){
    int i, j;
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("\nEnter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    for(i=1; i<=r; i++){
        for(j=1;j<=c; j++){
            scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
            m_sum = m_sum + m[i][j];
        }
    }

}
print_elements(int m[10][10], int r, int c, int m_sum){
    int i, j;
    printf("\n\nThe matrix is: \n\n");
    for(i=1; i<=r; i++){
        for(j=1;j<=c; j++){
            printf("%d", m[i][j]);
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\nThe sum of the elements are : %d", m_sum);
}
```

Comment: Side note about `for(i=1; i<=r; i++)` etc. In C arrays are indexed from `0` to, say, `r-1`. So you would usually expect to see `for(i=0; i<r; i++)`

Comment: Also note that the values assigned to function arguments `r, c, m_sum` inside the functions do not find their way back to variables with the same name in `main()`. And your functions have no return type, such as `int` or `void`.

Comment: Please describe what is happening when you try and run the code. Does it compile? If it doesn't, what are the compiler errors/warnings?

Comment: It does not compile. Not enough arguments with `add_elements(m, r, c);`

Comment: Compile it in DEV C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code which prints the matrix and the sum correctly.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
add_elements(int m[10][10], int *r, int *c, int *m_sum)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", r);
    printf("\nEnter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", c);
    for(i=0; i<*r; i++){
        for(j=0;j<*c; j++){
            scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
            *m_sum = *m_sum + m[i][j];
        }
    }

}
print_elements(int m[10][10], int r, int c, int m_sum)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\n\nThe matrix is: \n\n");
    for(i=0; i<r; i++){
        for(j=0;j<c; j++){
            printf("%d", m[i][j]);
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\nThe sum of the elements are : %d", m_sum);
}
int main()
{
    int m[10][10], r, c, m_sum=0;
    add_elements(m, &r, &c,&m_sum);
    print_elements(m, r, c, m_sum);
}
```

Some errors fixed:

1. The functions should be declared before they are called,thatis,
   before `main()`
2. The array index in C is from `0` to `n-1`, and not from `1` to `n`
3. `m_sum` was not initialized to `0`
4. Number of parameters were not same for add elements
5. The values of `r`, `c` and `m_sum` were not getting updated after returning
   from `add_elements()` to `main(`) function. So, I passed them as
   pointers to the function.